# FileReader wont work when 2 jquery libreries are imported

Tags: jquery

I am trying to add datepicker for browser which does not support date input type and FileReader for all browsers using jquery below is my code

```
<head>                  
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:100" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"</script>  
    </head>

<body>
  <input id="file_input" type="file" name="images" multiple>
 <input type="date" name="date1" id="date1" >
 <input type="date" name="date2" id="date2" >
  <img name="image1" id="display_image1"  class="display_main_image"  />
   <script type="text/javascript">
                    /*program for browsers which does not support date and time */
          var datefield=document.createElement("input")
          datefield.setAttribute("type", "date")
          if (datefield.type!="date"){
               $('#date1').val('<?php echo(date('d/m/Y')); ?>');
               $('#date2').val('<?php echo(date('d/m/Y')); ?>');
                       // load files for jQuery UI Date Picker
               document.write('<link href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />\n');
               document.write('<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4/jquery.min.js" id="remove_src"><\/script>\n');
               document.write('<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/jquery-ui.min.js"><\/script>\n');
                    }
   </script>

    <script>
     if (datefield.type!="date"){ //if browser doesn't support input type="date", initialize date picker widget:
                        jQuery(function($){ //on document.ready
                            $('#date1').datepicker();
                            $('#date2').datepicker();
                        });
                    }
     </script>

      <script>
             document.getElementById("file_input").onchange = function () {
                            var reader = new FileReader();
                            reader.onload = function (e) {
                                    document.getElementById("display_image1").src = e.target.result;   
                                }   
                            reader.readAsDataURL(this.files[0]);
                        };
             </script>
</body>
```

The problem I am facing is that if i add jquery 1.4 for browsers which does not support date input type the jquery is not calling onchange or onload functions hence I am not able to render the images this problem is only for browsers which does not support date format . If I comment out the link for jquery 1.4  rendering the images works

Note: rendering the images works on browser which support date format mainly because link for jquery 1.4 in not added

Can anyone please advice me, know can I make both datepicker and  FileReader work in browsers that do not support date input type

Thanks in advance.:)

Answer (score 0):

jQuery with version 1.x should be backward compatible, so you should be able to safely remove v1.4 without any problem.
Two concurrent jQuery Version will inevitably lead to some conflicting code.

There are also several potential issues with your code:
First: In the FileReader Script you are not using jquerys methods but vanilla javascript code.
(jquery would be something like `$("#selector").change()`, whereas you are selecting via `getElementById` which is a native Browser functionality.)

This might be a case, why this code does not work.

Second: ondocumentready handler (as the comment in Datepicker part suggests, that you intend to run on document ready) looks usually like this:
`$( document ).ready(function() {
    //Do your stuff
});`

Please check also to your Javascript-Console in your browser for any error message (usually opens up via F12 key).

EDIT:
Also please note that while writing  references in body is no problem,  to css scripts might cause all kinds of problems and errors concerning the UI, as  is only allowed to be in the  section of a html doc.

Comment: Hi jbin, Thanks for your replay i have also tried change method using jquery selector i.e.,$("#selector").change() and changing on document ready method also does not seem to work. how can I remove v1.4 I have tried var = document.getElementById ("script_v1.4");//id for v1.4 jquery
var.parentNode.removeChild(var); this did not work

Comment: This is the line where you add the jQuery library v1.4:                `document.write('<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4/jquery.min.js" id="remove_src"><\/script>\n');`

Comment: I can remove the v1.4 but still not able to solve the FilerRender problem. Also, I cannot see some of the tooltips I am using when the jquery v1.4 is present